# How to add a new function to an exsiting Type class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am currently trying to understand Haskell Type-Classes. After creating the simple example below and seeing that it works ....

```
data MyMaybe a = MyNothing | MyJust a
    deriving(Show)

class IncreaseByOne a where
    addOne :: a -> a

instance (Num a) => IncreaseByOne (MyMaybe a) where
    addOne  MyNothing = (MyNothing)
    addOne (MyJust x) = (MyJust (x+1))
```

asked my self: Is it possible to add the function *addOne* to the existing Type-Class **Num**. So all Numbers can make use of the function *addOne*. Something like:

```
instance IncreaseByOne Num where
    addOne x = x+1
```

Comment: FWIW, that particular behaviour already exists. It's [`succ` from the `Enum` type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can in principle write instances like

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
instance (Num a) => IncreaseByOne a where
  addOne x = x+1     -- or `addOne = (+1)`
```

The `-XUndecidableInstances` is not really a problem, but what's a problem is that this instance *overlaps* with any other instances you might want to declare, specifically with your `MyMaybe` one. The reason there's a problem there is that nothing in principle stops you from also having, maybe only later on in a module further downstream,

```
instance Num a => Num (MyMaybe a) where ...
```

and then *both* the `Num a => IncreaseByOne a` and `Num a => IncreaseByOne (MyMaybe a)` would apply.

GHC *can* do overlapping instances, but it's usually a bad idea. I would suggest you instead just write out short instances for all the concrete types that are relevant. To make this extra concise, you can have a default implementation based on `Num`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class IncreaseByOne a where
  addOne :: a -> a
  default addOne :: Num a => a -> a
  addOne = (+1)

instance (Num a) => IncreaseByOne (MyMaybe a) where
  addOne = fmap (+1)   -- `MyMaybe` _should_ have a `Functor` instance!

instance IncreaseByOne Int       -- note no instance body is needed,
instance IncreaseByOne Integer   -- because the default implementation
instance IncreaseByOne Double    -- applies
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth noting that you can just define a free-standing function. Unlike in Java or C#, where free functions (erm, `static` functions) are different and are called differently than instance functions, in Haskell there's really no difference. So, if all you want to do is make a function that works for all `Num`, here it is.

```
addOne :: Num a => a -> a
addOne = (+1)
```

No typeclasses necessary. That type signature literally reads as "for all numbers `a`, takes an `a` and returns an `a`".

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't specialise to `addOne :: MyMaybe Int -> MyMaybe Int`, unless `MyMaybe Int` is also given a `Num` instance (which would likely not be a good idea).

Comment: True, but I would also argue that having a function that works for "all `Num` and then this one random non-numerical thing" is probably a code smell anyway.

Comment: If it's just “this one random non-numerical thing” then yeah, but actually there are as many types `Num a => MyMaybe a` as `Num a => a`, and who knows what other instances the OP would also like to add.